# Reading from csv into Dataframe referenced from Dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to read in a number of csv files into dataframes.
I've associated the name of the csv to the dataframe in a dictionary:

```
dfs = dict()
dfs['DictProject'] = config.DictProject
```

I then call the following function to read the csv:

```
def readDict():
    global dfs
    for name, df in dfs.items():
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(config.PrjRoot, name+".csv")) == True:
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(config.PrjRoot, name+".csv"), index_col=1)
            display(df)
    return None
```

I would like DictProject.csv to be loaded into dataframe config.DictProject.
The csv is read correctly but not into config.DictProject.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please post your attempt at solving this? Also what type is `config`? Is it the DataFrame or is `DictProject` the DataFrame?

Comment: The code above was the closest I came and I didn't know where to go from here. config.DictProject is the Dataframe - it is shared between modules.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use dynamic code:

```
def readDict():
    global dfs
    for name, df in dfs.items():
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(config.PrjRoot, name+".csv")) == True:
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(config.PrjRoot, name+".csv"), index_col=1)
            prgtxt = 'config.' + name + ' = df'
            exec(prgtxt)
    return None
```